# Do Shapeshifters, like Odo, shift just shape, or composition as well?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, biology, changeling

When Odo is shaped as a humanoid, for example, is his eye just the outward shape of an eye? Or does he have a lens, and a retina, and an optic nerve, and a brain made of neurons processing images?

Comment: Although you seem to be asking about their composition specifically when in humanoid form, Odo does make the comment in one episode that if you were to scan him when he's a rock all you would detect is a rock. So to a degree they are exactly what they appear to be through and through, at least when simulating simpler objects.

Comment: @Xantec Possibly. That comment on Odo's part also supports the interpretation that they have some sensor-masking ability that automatically works to fool such scans into seeing what they would see if it were a real rock instead of a shapeshifter rock.

Comment: @MatthewNajmon although possible, it's a rather complicated scenario. I prefer Occam's Razor when there's no other evidence.

Comment: @Xantec You're misusing Occam's Razor. The razor is for situations where you're forced to make a decision without access to all relevant data, and is a useful guide to the best assumptions to base such a decision on. Using it to reach a conclusion when the data doesn't warrant conclusiveness is logically fallacious. When hearing hoofbeats, assuming horses is only slightly less severely wrong than assuming zebras; the correct stance is to conclude hoofed animal, and to leave the question of specific species unresolved pending further data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Changelings do not normally have nervous systems and organs when they take humanoid form, but may be able to simulate them when necessary.

When Odo assumes a humanoid form, he has no detectable brain. From the *DS9* episode ["Dramatis Personae"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/418.htm):

> **ODO:** Doctor, I believe the Klingon brought the matrix with him and everyone in Ops was affected except me. Without a humanoid brain, my system rejected it.

If there is no brain, then there are no nerves, optic or otherwise.

For another statement about the lack of nervous systems — but from Beta material — we have the following excerpt from *[Deep Space Nine Rebels: Book One](https://books.google.ca/books?id=vLMXcXEYDOEC)* by Dafydd ab Hugh:

> Founders — Changelings — didn't have a distinct central nervous system or brain, of course...the Founders' mental activity occurred everywhere and nowhere.

Concerning other organs, we have the following statement from Odo in the episode ["The Forsaken"](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/417.htm):

> **ODO:** I don't eat. This is not a real mouth, it is an approximation of one. I do not have an esophagus or a stomach or a digestive system. I am not like you.

(Thanks to **@ThePopMachine** for digging this one up!)

Taking all of this together, it would seem that Odo, even when taking humanoid form, has none of the organs that a humanoid would normally have.  What we see on his exterior is for appearance's sake only.

Of course, if there are no physical manifestations of a nervous system within a Changeling who is *infiltrating a humanoid community*, then a such an individual could be caught by a rather simple medical scan.  This would suggest that skilled Changelings ought to be able to simulate not only the internal appearance but also the electrical activity of a nervous system, in order to pass a basic tricorder test for being a humanoid.  (This must be the case, since we know from several *DS9* episodes that Changeling impostors are very difficult to detect.)

We also know that shape-changing is taxing on a Changeling.  It would stand to reason that when a Changeling is *not* trying to fool solids (e.g. Odo on a normal day), then a Changeling would probably not be simulating a nervous system, given the complexity of the feat.  Also, it may be that only very few Changelings have the endurance and skill required for it.

All in all, we can safely asssume that, when Odo assumes his humanoid form under normal circumstances, he has no brain, nerves, or organs, and his "eyes" are just for appearance's sake.

Comment: That is strange though. They must have at least a brain,... that at least simulate normal neurons firing (even without them having no effect). As else tricorders could easily pick out every shapechanger (which they can't)

Comment: @Thomas : I always like to give Star Trek the benefit of the doubt, but I think that's just a plot hole. Or at least the start of a new question. ;-)

Comment: Conservation of mass is a serious problem with what we saw Odo do as well.  Not to mention that guy that turned into fog.

Comment: @OrganicMarble : Indeed.

Comment: @Thomas : I refocused the answer in light of your comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Considering the Great Link turned Odo completely into a human he would've also needed all the internal organs necessary to support that form, nervous system included.

Comment: @Praxis Your last two paragraphs are probably the most accurate. Odo himself says that he doesn't do humanoids very well on multiple occasions (see his ears and face), so it is questionable whether *he* could perfectly simulate a central nervous system at all. But we do see Founders replace high ranking officers in both Starfleet and the Klingon Defense Force (Bashir and Martok were replaced for several months), so it stands to reason that they can make themselves indistinguishable when needed.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed this quote which is particularly apt.
(@Praxis, feel free to add to your answer if you like.)

From the first season episode "[The Forsaken](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/417.htm)":

> LWAXANA: I know. I'll have Quark send one of his minions with our basket. We'll have our picnic up there.
>
> ODO: Madame Ambassador.
>
> LWAXANA: Lwaxana.
>
> ODO: I don't eat. **This is not a real mouth, it is an approximation of one. I do not have an esophagus or a stomach or a digestive system.** I am not like you. Every sixteen hours, I turn into a liquid.

Comment: Calling @Praxis

Comment: Great find, +1.  I'll merge it into my answer --- thanks!